# How to ensure uniqueness in Labeled index in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

How can I ensure the put if absent /create unique functionality while creating nodes using labeled indexes in Core Java API? Earlier I would get an Index from Index Manager and just fire putIfAbsent. But now after I create a label and index it, lets say a User label with userId as indexed property, I cannot get the index like I used to. The method graphDb.index().existsForNodes("User") always returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like merge in Cypher which is not exposed in the JAVA API, AFAIK
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-merge.html#merge-merge-single-node-with-properties

If you need one please open an issue on Github 
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I posted the same question on neo4j disqus forum. I am told that uniqueness is supposed to be enforced by the uniqueness constraint. However it is not available in current milestone.